# Plotting multispectral satellite tiff image in python

Tags: python, plot, gis, tiff

I'm trying to verify/plot satellite images in python using tifffile lib.

For RGB photos with three channels I don't have a problem and can view them as expected but when I try a 8 channel SWIR image things seem to break:

```
img_3 = np.transpose(tiff.imread("imageRGB.tif"),(1,2,0))
img_a = np.transpose(tiff.imread("imageA.tif"),(1,2,0))

img_3.shape: (3349L, 3396L, 3L)
img_a.shape: (3349L, 3396L, 8L)


tifffile.imshow(img_a)
```

[image]

While `tifffile.imshow(img_3)`shows the expected image in a nice rectangle. 
The only way i can plot (part of) img_a is if i choose a specific channel like:

```
tifffile.imshow(img_a[:,:,1])
```

What am i missing?

Comment: `imshow` does not know which dimension of the numpy array are spatial or spectral. By default it assumes the spatial dimensions are last unless the last dimension is 3 or 4 (RGBA). In your case, move the spectral dimension to the front: `tifffile.imshow(numpy.moveaxis(img_a, 2, 0)) `

Comment: yes that's it .. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The specteral dimension should be on the first axis for tiff.imshow() to work properly.

`tiff.imshow(np.rollaxis(img_a,2,0))` will do the trick.